# Словообразование, суффикс -ЩИК

Tags: словообразование

Цитирую из Википедии (суффикс -щик):

> в безударной позиции при добавлении к
> основе глагола образует
> существительное со значением «тот, кто
> связан с указанной в основе
> деятельностью, профессией, орудием или
> материалом труда» ◆ точить → точильщик

Но, к примеру, слова

> барабанщик, трактирщик, бакалейщик, конвейерщик

в моём понимании образованы от соответствующих существительных. Отсюда вопросы:

1. Насколько верно приведённое правило?
2. Есть ли профессиональная литература по словообразованию, где приведены все словообразующие аффиксы с примерами и значением (в плане словообразования)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Но, к примеру, слова
>
> ```
> барабанщик, трактирщик, бакалейщик, конвейерщик
> ```
>
> в моём понимании образованы от
> соответствующих существительных.

Конечно, от существительных.

> Есть ли профессиональная литература по
> словообразованию, где приведены все
> словообразующие аффиксы с примерами и
> значением (в плане словообразования)?

См., к примеру, http://dic.academic.ru/dic.nsf/efremova/271729 :

> **-щик-**
>
> I. *суффикс*; = -чик-
>
> Словообразовательная единица,
> образующая имена существительные -
> названия лиц мужского пола,
> характеризующиеся отношением к тому,
> что названо образующими словами и
> определяет их деятельность, характер,
> ремесло, занятие
>
> 1) лицо, характеризующееся отношением
> к предмету или явлению, названному
> образующим именем существительным
> *(ба́нщик, буфе́тчик, водопрово́дчик, лита́врщик, нату́рщик, парке́тчик и
> т.п.)*
>
> 2) лицо, характеризующееся отношением к признаку или предмету,
> названному образующим именем
> прилагательным или словосочетанием с
> опорным прилагательным в качестве
> определения *(газовщи́к, жестя́нщик,
> кладовщи́к, часово́й ма́стер -
> часовщи́к, я́дерная фи́зика - я́дерщик
> и т.п.)*
>
> 3) лицо, производящее действие,
> названное глаголами, от которых
> соответствующие имена существительные
> образованы *(оби́дчик, обхо́дчик,
> поку́пщик, прове́рщик, разно́счик,
> ре́зчик, танцо́вщик и т.п.).*
>
> II *суффикс*; = -чик-
>
> Словообразовательная единица,
> образующая имена существительные
> мужского рода со значением предмета -
> машины, механизма, приспособления,
> которые производят действия, названные
> глаголами, от которых соответствующие
> имена существительные образованы
> *(бомбардиро́вщик, буксиро́вщик, погру́зчик, счётчик, тра́льщик и
> т.п.).*
>
> ***Толковый словарь Ефремовой. Т. Ф. Ефремова. 2000.***